# Max number of sessions per entity in Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Azure Service Bus allows to use sessioned entities(queues and topics), we use them to keep batching processing by the same consumer(if we send a batch from producer, it must be processed by the same consumer service). I cannot find any recommendations about max allowed sessions number per entity, we have 4 sessions for 1000 000 messages for now and I am wondered if we can increase the number. If we can, what is max possible value for my case?

Short info about my process:
* 1 000 000 messages to be sent to ASB entity
* Batch size is 100 messages
* Number of sessions is 4
* ASB entities have enabled sessions and partitioning

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Azure Service Bus quotas [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas) doesn't spell out a limit on number of concurrent session you can have.

You are limitted by two factors:

1. The number of concurrent connecitons on a namespace (5,000 for AMQP and 1,000 for SBMP)
2. Number of concurrent receive request per entity (5,000) you can have.

As long as you don't exceed those quotas, you should be able to scale out your receiver to handle more sessions.

Comment: but as far as I understand 1 connection is sufficient to process more than 1 session as long as its the very same consumer, so you can have many more sessions than that 5000

Comment: Sessions are not connections. Connection is physical. Sessions share the connection. But you won’t push through a single connection an infinite number of sessions as performance will be degraded, keep that in mind.

Comment: exactly, but between 1 and infinity there is quite a big range, would be good to know what are the reasonable numbers :)

Comment: There's not specific number you'd find in the documentation. That'd be a question to the Service Bus service team, not the community.