# Are there any limitation on the number of partitions in a Azure Service Bus Queue or Topics?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I understand there are only a max of 100 partition queues allowed per namespace from the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-partitioning#partitioned-entities-limitations). But are there any max number of partitions are allowed in a queue?

Thank you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan, I checked the link but it still did not specify the max number of sessions (partition) a queue can hold.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-partitioning#partitioned-entities-limitations

Comment: same for this link as well. it still does not provide the ans to my qn

Comment: Misunderstood your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51942549/max-number-of-sessions-per-entity-in-azure-service-bus there is no doc for this now

Comment: I see. in that case, is it correct to understand there is no limit on the number of sessions in a queue?

Comment: Partitioned entities and sessions are two different things.

Comment: Sort of. But each sessions end up being partition in each entities.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  [Sajeetharan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1749403/sajeetharan)   ,
Based on the [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-partitioning#:%7E:text=Service%20Bus%20currently%20allows%20up,t%20apply%20to%20Premium%20tier%29.)

> Currently Service bus allows **up to 100 partitioned queues or topics
> per namespace**. Each partitioned queue or topic counts towards the
> quota of 10,000 entities per namespace (doesn't apply to Premium
> tier).

There is no doc. for limit of number of concurrent sessions as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51942549/max-number-of-sessions-per-entity-in-azure-service-bus) .

Please refer this for more information about sessions  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions .